# How to configure Package Manager Console to show long version strings

Tags: nuget

I use Get-Package to list all the versions available for a particular library.  However, the Version strings are too long, and the actual version number at the end is cut out.  What can I do to make it show?

Sample output below

```
Id                             Version              Description/Release Notes                                                                              
--                             -------              -------------------------                                                                              
xunit                          2.0.0-beta4-build... xUnit.net  ....
xunit.core                     2.0.0-beta4-build... Includes ....
```

I'd need the information at the end of "2.0.0-beta4-build".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to use PowerShell's format-list to change the formatting.

```
get-package | format-list -property id, version
```

The above PowerShell command will display output similar to the following:

```
Id      : xunit
Version : 2.0.0-beta4-build2738

Id      : xunit.abstractions
Version : 2.0.0-beta4-build2738

Id      : xunit.assert
Version : 2.0.0-beta4-build2738

Id      : xunit.core
Version : 2.0.0-beta4-build2738
```